# Wrong result through brute counting of basic permutation.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let us say that we have $10$ orators and out of them a chosen set of three speakers (James, Max and Born) is to always speak in the respective order (J $\rightarrow$ M $\rightarrow$ B)

This is a standard and basic permutation problem and the answer can be attained by simply permuting all the members and cancel out permutations of $J$, $M$, and $B$ which don't follow the same order and finally we will get

$$ \fbox {$\text{# of ways} = \frac{10!}{3!}$}$$

But this seems to be a good problem if we don't apply this logic and make cases.
Using the stars and bars kind of approach we can have a scenario as follows

$$ \ldots J \ldots M \ldots B \ldots$$
where any kind of arrangement of the rest seven people can be inserted into the dots.

Since we have $7$ people left, we arrange them into $1 \: \text{slot}$, $2 \: \text{slots}$, $3 \:  \text{slots}$ and $4 \: \text{slots}$ to put them into the vacant spaces.

There is only $7!$ ways to arrange $7$ people into one group and then we have $P(4,1)$ to put them in any vacant position.

$$\text{# of ways with 7 people in one group} = 7! \cdot 4 \: \tag1$$

Through elementary combinatorics we know that the number of ways to arrange $n$ distinct objects into $r$ distinct groups is 
$$ n! \cdot {n-1 \choose r-1}$$

Diving $7$ people into $2$ groups (with no admittance for a blank group) and then arranging them in $2$ places out of $4$

$$ \text{# of ways} = 7! \cdot {6 \choose 1} \cdot P(4,2) \tag2$$
Doing the same thing for $7$ people into $3$ groups:
$$ \text{# of ways} = 7! \cdot {6 \choose 2} \cdot P(4,3) \tag3$$
Again the same stuff for $7$ people into $4$ groups:
$$\text{# of ways} = 7! \cdot {6 \choose 3} \cdot P(4,4) \tag4$$

Hence we get

$$\text{Total # of ways} = 7! \left\{4 + {6 \choose 1} \cdot P(4,2)  +{6 \choose 2} \cdot P(4,3) + {6 \choose 3} \cdot P(4,4) \right\}$$

This is certainly not the equal to the correct answer which we got in the beginning i.e. $\frac{10!}{3!}$.

Can you please tell me where I have faltered during the counting?

Comment: I can't figure out where your $P(4,1)$ comes in.

Comment: Since we are having four vacant spaces (which I marked by dots) where we can put these groups.

Comment: I still can't figure out what you mean here.

Comment: $P(4,1)$ is denoting the number of ways to put the 1 group in one of the 4 vacant spaces. First I partitioned people into groups and then counted the number of ways to fill the vacant spaces with the groups through the permutation formula.

Comment: Why do you think that the answer is $10!/3!$? I got that the answer is ${6\choose 3}=20$ using [stars and bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: It should be $4\choose i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$, not $P(4,i)$. You're choosing which of the four vacant spaces you're using, but they are already ordered because they represent spaces in your ordered list.

Comment: @KevinLong Pardon me for my ignorance, but why should it be a combination and not a permutation? When I have my groups and I want to insert them into the vacant spaces, for the first group I can choose any of the 4 places, for the rest I can go on in the same manner. Why doesn't this approach (of using permutations) work?

Comment: You've already ordered your seven people from first to last as are your spaces. The first people should go in the first space, or you've violated the original order. You'll end up double counting as permuting the spaces will also change the permutation of the people.

Comment: I advise you, Harsh, to take a much smaller case – say, speakers $A,B,C,D$, where $A$ must precede $B$ – where you can actually write down all the possibilities, and I think you will be able to see where you are overcounting.

Comment: @KevinLong Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks Sir. I will certainly try to do it that way.

Comment: Any progress to report, Harsh?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.